# How do i get failed login message in console?

Tags: linux, login

Hi guys one of my server shows like
There was 1 failed login attempt since the last successful login. Whenever i failed login.

But the other servers does not show that message even though I failed login. How can I get these messages ??

Funny part is that these servers have the same settings..

Comment: Maybe there is a setting to log them.  There is an article [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/rhel-centos-fedora-linux-log-failed-login.html)

Comment: thx but mine is rhel8.6 so i dont think the article suits for me :)                     Also, my /etc/pam.d/system-auth are all same but only this server shows that massage… idk why